# Oracle script conversion to MySQL 5.0 script

Tags: mysql

Does any one know open source/ commercial tool to convert Oracle sql script to MySQL script?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://www.swissql.com/products/sql-translator/sqlone-consolejava-downloadform.html

Comment: Pretty good but it failed to convert the creation of users and the granting of permissions.